# Scrolling in Modal makes background scroll on Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, modal-dialog, vertical-scrolling

I need to have some help with an annoying thing.
I have an modal popup which has vertical scrollsbar inside. When scrolling inside the modal sometimes the background scrolls instead.
I have tried to add

```
body{
position:relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

which works fine on most of the browsers, but Safari for my iPhone still scrolls!

Please help me find how to solve this!

Regards Kristian

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
$('body').css('position','fixed');
```

Did it for me.

Comment: If you've already scrolled down before opening the modal, then setting body to fixed with overflow hidden will force the body to scroll back up.

Comment: @matb33 so any fix that didn't scroll to the top

Comment: @adit not without introducing some javascript. It might be possible to shift the body upwards (position: relative; top: -x) the distance of scrollTop, but this will probably have other setbacks if the browser can be resized.